# can I install ubuntu on windows 10

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded ubuntu iso on windows 10.

I have tried double click on iso file but windows asks for application to use.
how do I start the iso?

Is it secure to run ubuntu under windows 10?

Comment: Ubuntu does provide a procedure for installing Ubuntu alongside an existing Windows operating system by resizing the partition and creating a separate area for the Ubuntu installation, but they do not recommend it, and the procedure predates Windows 10 so there's no guarantee it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "install" ubuntu on windows 10 because ubuntu is an operating system like windows.  If you want to try to run Ubuntu in windows 10 you can download [virtualbox for windows 10](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds) (it's a little buggy right now).  Then, once it's installed checkout [this article](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox) on installing ubuntu from virtualbox.